# Probability of $x$ trials given $k$ successes

Tags: probability, negative-binomial, bernoulli-distribution

I am looking for a probability distribution that calculates the probability of $x$ total Bernoulli trials given fixed $k$ successes.

I have looked into negative binomial distribution:
$$
P(X=x) = \binom{x-1}{k-1} p^k (1-p)^{x-k}
$$
where:

- $x$ is the number of Bernoulli trials (not fixed)
- $k$ is the number of successes (fixed)
- $p$ is the probability of success (fixed)

But I've read that this particular negative binomial distribution calculates the probability of $x$ trials UNTIL the $k$th success. I might be wrong, but this is not the same as what I am looking for, which is the probability of $x$ trials, given $k$ successes.

If they are the same, can someone explain how they are equivalent?
The Wikipedia page is confusing to me.

Comment: In order to find the probability of $x$ trials given $k$ successes, you have to have some notion of what the probability of $x$ trials is. The negative binomial distribution works because the probability of $x$ trials is simply the probability that the $k$th success occurs on the $x$th trial. That is, it is understood that you will always stop trying after the $k$th success. If you are allowed to continue beyond $k$ successes, when do you stop making new trials?

Comment: One interpretation is, since you do not stop making new trials after the $k$th success, and there is no other reason to stop the trials, you just keep on making trials and never stop. So the probability of stopping at $x$ trials is always zero. So is the probability of getting exactly $k$ successes. The conditional probability is undefined.

Comment: @DavidK can we compute the probability of  trials as 
$$
\frac
{\sum_{i=0}^x p^i(1-p)^{x-i}}
{\sum_{j=0}^∞ \sum_{i=0}^j p^i(1-p)^{x-i}}
$$

Comment: That formula looks highly dubious. Can you explain in words what is the rationale behind it? The top appears to be the probability that in $x$ trials you get all the successes before any of the failures.

Comment: The numerator is the sum of the probability of every permutation of  trials (e.g.  successes and (-) failures).
The denominator is the sum of sums, where  trials go from 0 to ∞.

Comment: The numerator is **not** the sum of probabilities of all permutations. You have left out the factor $\binom xi$. If you put that factor in both sums, the top sum becomes $1$ and the bottom sum becomes $\sum_{j=0}^\infty 1$.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to add the "binomial coefficient"

Comment: It appears that you have an ill-defined question. It might help if you explained in the question why you are asking this. If the reason is something other than idle curiosity, someone might be able to figure out what it is that you really need.

Comment: This question is in response to one of the questions I've been going through in school. Though, I suspect it has been worded wrongly. However, I am still interested in this probability distribution and have been thinking about it for hours. Yes, this can be categorized as idle curiosity. Are questions like these welcome here?

Comment: Idle curiosity is a wonderful thing in a student. Sometimes it leads you somewhere interesting. In this case it leads to philosophical questions of what we would even mean by such a question.

Comment: For those wondering, the original question simpliefied: "The probability of a delivery is returned is 40%. Suppose that 5 deliveries were returned, what is the probability that this was out of 10 deliveries?"

Comment: @DavidK thanks, I'll definitely have some closure knowing that this question was ill-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is relevant to the concept of conditional probability. Recall the Bayes' theorem
$$P(X=x|k) = \frac{P(X=x)P(k|X=x)}{P(k)}=\frac{P(X=x)P(k|X=x)}{\sum_i P(X=i)P(k|X=i)}$$

We can back out the desired distribution LHS from RHS. In particular we make use of $P(k|X)$, which is the binomial distribution.

Without conditioning on $k$ and without a given prior distribution of $X$, the number of trials $X$ can be assumed to follow a uniform distribution. Thus, $P(X=i)$ is a constant and the equation can be reduced to
$$P(X=x|k) = \frac{P(k|X=x)}{\sum_i P(k|X=i)}$$

First of all, it is obvious that $X\geq k$.

For every $X\geq k$, $P(k|X=x) = C^x_kp^k(1-p)^{x-k}$.

Therefore,

$$P(X=x|k) = \frac{C^x_kp^k(1-p)^{x-k}}{\sum_{i=k}^\infty C^i_kp^k(1-p)^{i-k}}$$
$$=\frac{C^x_k(1-p)^{x-k}}{\sum_{i=k}^\infty C^i_k(1-p)^{i-k}}$$
$$=\underline{\underline{C^x_k(1-p)^{x-k}p^{k+1}}} (*)$$ ($*$)For the sum of the infinite series, please refer to the comment section below.

Now, compare this result with the negative binomial distribution $C^{x-1}_{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{x-k}$. As a matter of fact, they highly resemble each other. The differences lie in the binomial coefficient and the number of success trials:

$$C^x_k \text{ vs } C^{x-1}_{k-1}$$
$$p^{k+1} \text{ vs } p^k$$

The intuitive explanation is as follows.

The negative binomial is a distribution of the trials **until** the $k$th success. Therefore, the last trial must yield a success, which means that the permutation is applied to the first ($x$-1) trials only that contains ($k$-1) successes.

On the other hand, the desired distribution does not have this restriction, so the permutation includes one more successful trial.

Comment: How did you simplify the sum of the infinite series to get 

$$=\underline{\underline{C^x_k(1-p)^{x-k}p^{k+1}}}$$

Comment: @MarcusChiu Thanks to Sir Isaac Newton for the discovery of binomial expansion for negative indices, which states that
$$(1-x)^{-n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty C^{n+i-1}_ix^i$$

Consider $S=\sum_{i=k}^\infty C^i_k(1-p)^{i-k}$.

Substitute $u=i-k$. Then
$$S=\sum_{u=0}^\infty C^{u+k}_k(1-p)^u$$
$$=\sum_{u=0}^\infty C^{(k+1)+u-1}_u(1-p)^u$$
$$=[1-(1-p)]^{-(k+1)}=\underline{\underline{p^{-(k+1)}}}$$

Comment: This is an interesting derivation, but it assumes the existence of a uniform distribution over all positive integers. If you instead assume a uniform distribution over $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ and let $N\to\infty$ then I suppose you will get the same result in the limit.

Comment: Is it reasonable to expect the mean number of trials  given  successes to be /? (i.e. [] = /)